# Scrolling an element which loads further on scrolling using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create an Instagram scraping bot that collects a list of Followers and Following using Python + Selenium.

However, that list keeps on loading when the user scrolls until the list is exhausted. I am attaching a screenshot for reference (some content hidden due to privacy reasons):

[image]

Now, I believe I have two ways to achieve this:

1. Keep reading the usernames, and then keep on scrolling.
2. Keep scrolling till the end, and then read all usernames together from the source code.

I've been trying to figure this out using the second method. However, I am not able to figure out how to know when there is no more content to scroll. How can I achieve this (provided that I don't know anything about the length of this element)?

**Reason for not using Method 1:** When scrolling, the DOM keeps getting refreshed, so it is hard to keep track of which usernames have been read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is is to keep track of the amount of child elements the `div` has that contains the `li` elements for the followers. If it doesn't increase after a scroll event, you've reached the end of the list.

Comment: Yes, this crossed my mind. But this would require to check the count of `li` elements after every scroll. That seemed to be quite a waste of computational power.

Comment: I tried some other things as well like scrolling down `total_users / users_scrolled_in_one_KEY_DOWN` times but that did not work smoothly. So I adapted your idea but changed `KEY_DOWN` to `END` signal so there are fewer repetition in calculating the count of `li` tags. Leaving it out in the comments as it might help someone else.

Comment: I was expecting something which could provide me with a signal when scrolling can't be done further. However, this has helped. Accepting this solution for now.